# How to clean up old Hive tables

Tags: hadoop, hive

We have been creating a large amount of temporary hive tables needed for intermediate calculations. Thing is, these tables are starting to get out of control and we came to the point in which we need to start doing some cleaning up.

As possible solution, we thought about having a shell script that runs as a cron job and deletes tables that are more x days old. This would do the trick but obviously we would like to know if there is something out there that does this already for you. Something like [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/3.3/older-than.html) but for hive/hadoop.

Comment: I don't really see how your shell script could *easily* get the "last DDL time" out of every Hive table (or every Hive table whose name starts with `temp_` and/or is located in DB `tempstuff`). That would require multiple steps of building the query, running the query, parsing the seult to build the next query, etc. On the other hand, a Java program accessing the Hive Metastore API would do the trick (although the documentation is sparse, i.e. you've got a JavaDoc with very little comments).

Comment: These tables got a suffix which is the creation date so we are covered in that sense. And yes, having a Java program seems to be a sensible option.